# JS .preventDefault not working

Tags: javascript, html, preventdefault

when i use the .preventDefault on a link it still goes to the link - also is this even doable with JS or is it a jquery only method?

```
var avoidlink = getElementsByTagName("a");

avoidlink.addEventListner("click",function(evt){
evt.preventDefault();
},false);


<a href="http://www.google.com">Click here</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three problems :

- `getElementsByTagName` must be called on the document or on an element
- You can't add an event listener directly on the node list returned by `getElementsByTagName`, you must iterate over the elements it contains :
- you have a typo in `addEventListener`

Here's a fixed code :

```
var avoidlink = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i=0; i<avoidlink.length; i++) {
  avoidlink[i].addEventListener("click",function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  },false);
}
```

---

If you want to be able to attach an event listener to a node list, you may enrich `NodeList.prototype` :

```
NodeList.prototype.addEventListener = function(){
  for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
      Element.prototype.addEventListener.apply(this[i] , arguments);
  }
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/vbG9Z/)

Modifying the prototype of objects you don't own is generally frowned upon but this change is rather innocuous and natural.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if many elements need the same event listener you can add the event listener to the container and filter out what element you would like to take action upon:

```
document.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  if(e.target,e.target.tagName.toLowerCase()==="a"){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

If you were to add extra anchor tags through script they will trigger the preventDefault too.